# Spring-Boot docker build with paketo fails on Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: spring-boot, bitbucket-pipelines, spring-boot-maven-plugin, buildpack, paketo

My spring-boot projekts builds its docker image on bitbucket.org using the spring-boot-maven-plugin with its build-image goal. On pipelines we always get the following maven error:

```
Docker API call to 'localhost:2375/v1.24/containers/create' failed with status code 403 "Forbidden"
```

In the docker log I found the following

```
time="2021-03-25T11:30:59Z" level=info msg="Container create request." ArgsEscaped=false AttachStderr=false AttachStdin=false AttachStdout=false ExposedPorts="map[]" Healthcheck="<nil>" Labels="map[author:spring-boot]" MacAddress= NetworkDisabled=false OnBuild="[]" OpenStdin=false StdinOnce=false StopSignal= StopTimeout="<nil>" Tty=false plugin=pipelines

time="2021-03-25T11:30:59Z" level=info msg="Container create request." AutoRemove=false BlkioDeviceReadBps="[]" BlkioDeviceReadIOps="[]" BlkioDeviceWriteBps="[]" BlkioDeviceWriteIOps="[]" BlkioWeight=0 BlkioWeightDevice="[]" CPUCount=0 CPUPercent=0 CPUPeriod=0 CPUQuota=0 CPURealtimePeriod=0 CPURealtimeRuntime=0 CPUShares=0 CapAdd="[]" CapDrop="[]" Capabilities="[]" Cgroup= CgroupParent= ConsoleSize="[0 0]" ContainerIDFile= CpusetCpus= CpusetMems= DNS="[]" DNSOptions="[]" DNSSearch="[]" DeviceCgroupRules="[]" Devices="[]" ExtraHosts="[]" GroupAdd="[]" IOMaximumBandwidth=0 IOMaximumIOps=0 Init="<nil>" IpcMode= Isolations= KernelMemory=0 Links="[]" LogConfig="{ map[]}" MaskedPaths="[]" Memory=0 MemoryReservation=0 MemorySwap=0 MemorySwappiness="<nil>" Mounts="[]" NanoCPUs=0 NetworkMode=default OomKillDisable="<nil>" OomScoreAdj=0 PidMode= PidsLimit="<nil>" PortBindings="map[]" Privileged=false PublishAllPorts=false ReadOnlyPaths="[]" RestartPolicy="{ 0}" Runtime= SecurityOpt="[]" ShmSize=0 StorageOpt="map[]" Sysctls="map[]" Ulimits="[]" UsernsMode= VolumeDriver= VolumesFrom="[]" plugin=pipelines

time="2021-03-25T11:30:59Z" level=info msg="Pipelines plugin request authorization." allowed=false method=POST plugin=pipelines uri=/v1.24/containers/createtime="2021-03-25T11:30:59.233599182Z" level=error msg="AuthZRequest for POST /v1.24/containers/create returned error: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: -v only supports $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR and its subdirectories"
```

I found a few posts with similar problems but no real explanation what is going wrong and if there is anything i can do about it.

There is an atlassian ticket where someone references this log https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-17592

I know that on my local machine there are lots of named volumes on the creator container

Comment: They have not solved this issue. I will have to consider other platforms for next enterprise projects.